# TFS2017 - NuGet push with octopack credentials

Tags: nuget, octopack

I'm having issues with pushing my packages to our internal NuGet feed that I created using TFS2017 packages tab.

I'm getting the following error:

```
2017-04-05T09:08:24.8336348Z      6>OctoPack:
2017-04-05T09:08:24.8336348Z          Please provide credentials for: http://servername:8080/tfs/TCol/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json
2017-04-05T09:08:24.9273850Z          Unable to load the service index for source http://servername:8080/tfs/TCol/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json.
2017-04-05T09:08:24.9273850Z            Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
2017-04-05T09:08:24.9273850Z          UserName: Password: 
2017-04-05T09:08:24.9430236Z ##[error]Source\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\OctoPack.targets(108,5): Error MSB3073: The command ""C:\TFS_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\2\s\Source\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\NuGet.exe" push "C:\TFS_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\2\s\Source\Company.Product.ServiceBus\obj\octopacked\Company.Product.ServiceBus.Release.3.5.0.nupkg"  -Source http://servername:8080/tfs/TCol/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json " exited with code 1.
2017-04-05T09:08:24.9430236Z      6>C:\TFS_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\2\s\Source\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\OctoPack.targets(108,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\TFS_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\2\s\Source\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\NuGet.exe" push "C:\TFS_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\2\s\Source\Company.Product.ServiceBus\obj\octopacked\Company.Product.ServiceBus.Release.3.5.0.nupkg"  -Source http://servername:8080/tfs/TCol/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json " exited with code 1. [C:\TFS_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\2\s\Source\Company.Product.ServiceBus\Company.Product.ServiceBus.csproj]
```

I want to push packages to it with OctoPack using the following build parameters:

```
/p:RunOctoPack=true 
/p:OctoPackPublishPackageToHttp=http://servername:8080/tfs/TCol/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json 
/p:OctoPackAppendToPackageId=Release 
/p:OctoPackNuGetProperties=Configuration=Release
```

I tried using the following:

```
/p:OctoPackPublishApiKey=VSTS
/p:OctoPackNuGetPushProperties=-ApiKey=VSTS
```

Neither parameters worked..

I also don't mind removing the apikey / credentials from the feed but there is literally NO documentation how to do this in the new Package feature in TFS 2017.

Here's a stacktrace I just printed out using `-Verbosity detailed` in the nuget push parameters:

```
  OctoPack: OctoPack successful
  Publish to repository: http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/COLL/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json
  "C:\********_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\7\s\Source\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\NuGet.exe" push "C:\********_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\7\s\Source\Company.Product.ApiProxy.v2\obj\octopacked\Company.Product.ApiProxy.v2.Release.3.5.0.nupkg"  -Source http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/COLL/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json -Verbosity detailed -ApiKey key
  NuGet Version: 3.5.0.10252 (Custom build for OctoPack)
  Please provide credentials for: http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/COLL/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json
  System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/COLL/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
     at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
     at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<<GetAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.<ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<GetAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.<GetServiceIndexResourceV3>d__9.MoveNext()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.<GetServiceIndexResourceV3>d__9.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.<TryCreate>d__8.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.<GetResourceAsync>d__16`1.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.PackageUpdateResourceV3Provider.<TryCreate>d__1.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.<GetResourceAsync>d__16`1.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.<GetResourceAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Commands.CommandRunnerUtility.<GetPackageUpdateResource>d__3.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Commands.PushRunner.<Run>d__0.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.CommandLine.PushCommand.<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
     at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
  ---> (Inner Exception #0) NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/COLL/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
     at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
     at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<<GetAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.<ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<GetAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.<GetServiceIndexResourceV3>d__9.MoveNext()
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.<GetServiceIndexResourceV3>d__9.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.<TryCreate>d__8.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.<GetResourceAsync>d__16`1.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.PackageUpdateResourceV3Provider.<TryCreate>d__1.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.<GetResourceAsync>d__16`1.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.<GetResourceAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Commands.CommandRunnerUtility.<GetPackageUpdateResource>d__3.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.Commands.PushRunner.<Run>d__0.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at NuGet.CommandLine.PushCommand.<ExecuteCommandAsync>d__28.MoveNext()<---

  UserName: Password: 
Source\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\OctoPack.targets(108,5): Error MSB3073: The command ""C:\********_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\7\s\Source\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\NuGet.exe" push "C:\********_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\7\s\Source\Company.Product.ApiProxy.v2\obj\octopacked\Company.Product.ApiProxy.v2.Release.3.5.0.nupkg" -Source http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/COLL/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json -Verbosity detailed -ApiKey key" exited with code 1.
C:\********_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\7\s\Source\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\OctoPack.targets(108,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\********_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\7\s\Source\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\NuGet.exe" push "C:\********_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\7\s\Source\Company.Product.ApiProxy.v2\obj\octopacked\Company.Product.ApiProxy.v2.Release.3.5.0.nupkg"  -Source http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/COLL/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json -Verbosity detailed -ApiKey key" exited with code 1. [C:\********_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\7\s\Source\Company.Product.ApiProxy.v2\Company.Product.ApiProxy.v2.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\********_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\7\s\Source\Company.Product.ApiProxy.v2\Company.Product.ApiProxy.v2.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Project "C:\********_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\7\s\Source\Company.Product.Solution.sln" (1) is building "C:\********_Agents\Product_Agent_1\_work\7\s\Source\Company.Product.ApiProxy.v2.TestConsole\Company.Product.ApiProxy.v2.TestConsole.csproj" (24) on node 1 (default targets).
```

Comment: Still having problems... (EDIT)

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you open a command line and execute

```
nuget push foo.nupkg your-api-key -source http://servername:8080/tfs/TCol/_packaging/Product/nuget/v3/index.json
```